# Can a member variable (attribute) reside in a register in C++?

Tags: c++, attributes, member, volatile, cpu-registers

A local variable (say an int) can be stored in a processor register, at least as long as its address is not needed anywhere. Consider a function computing something, say, a complicated hash:

```
int foo(int const* buffer, int size)
{
    int a;   // local variable
    // perform heavy computations involving frequent reads and writes to a
    return a;
}
```

Now assume that the buffer does not fit into memory. We write a class for computing the hash from chunks of data, calling `foo` multiple times:

```
struct A
{
    void foo(int const* buffer, int size)
    {
        // perform heavy computations involving frequent reads and writes to a
    }

    int a;
};

A object;
while (...more data...)
{
    A.foo(buffer, size);
}
// do something with object.a
```

The example may be a bit contrived. The important difference here is that `a` was a local variable in the free function and now is a member variable of the object, so the state is preserved across multiple calls.

Now the question: would it be legal for the compiler to load `a` at the beginning of the `foo` method into a register and store it back at the end? In effect this would mean that a second thread monitoring the object could never observe an intermediate value of `a` (synchronization and undefined behavior aside). Provided that speed is a major design goal of C++, this seems to be reasonable behavior. Is there anything in the standard that would keep a compiler from doing this? If no, do compilers actually do this? In other words, can we expect a (possibly small) performance penalty for using a member variable, aside from loading and storing it once at the beginning and the end of the function?

As far as I know, the C++ language itself does not even specify what a register is. However, I think that the question is clear anyway. Whereever this matters, I appreciate answers for a standard x86 or x64 architecture.

Comment: Check "register" and "volatile" flags

Comment: @amchacon Indeed C++ currently has a 'register' keyword. But I'd further point out that it is deprecated in C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can do that if (and only if) it can prove that nothing else will access `a` during `foo`'s execution.
That's a non-trivial problem in general; I don't think any compiler attempts to solve it.

Consider the (even more contrived) example

```
struct B
{
    B (int& y) : x(y) {}
    void bar() { x = 23; }
    int& x;
};

struct A
{
    int a;
    void foo(B& b)
    {
        a = 12;
        b.bar();            
    }
};
```

Looks innocent enough, but then we say

```
A baz;
B b(baz.a);
baz.foo(b);
```

"Optimising" this would leave `12` in `baz.a`, not `23`, and that is clearly wrong.

Comment: In the example, there is no multi-threading and the object is created locally, so how could the compiler not prove it and still prove it for a primitive?  Even for multi-threading, keeping variables in registers is actually a problem when accessing while not locked (actual problem is not locking).

Comment: I admit, it has a better chance of proving it if the function can be inlined.

Comment: Thank you for the example.  I was thinking more in terms of temporary staying in register during the loop, but I admit, there are limits to what compiler can prove, especially in combination with functions, However, don't forget that primitives can also have references.

Comment: Thanks, simple and enlighting example. So the fact that a member variable has a longer life time than a local variable (from the perspective of a member function) makes it hard to prove anything. And that again means that there is most probably a performance cost. Damn :)

Comment: @tglas On the (rare) occasion that it matters, you can do the computation locally and write to the member afterwards. I've needed to do that once or twice, but that was in very performance-sensitive code. (It can also make sense to do the computation locally if you want some invariant of your object to always hold.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to "Can a member variable (attribute) reside in a register?": yes.

When iterating through a buffer and writing the temporary result to any sort of primitive, wherever it resides, keeping the temporary result in a register would be a good optimization. This is done frequently in compilers.  However, it is implementation based, even influenced by passed flags, so to know the result, you should check the generated assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. That's what I expected and actually hoped for, it is good to know that my concerns are void.